# append a button after an event

Tags: jquery, append

I want to add a button after a option has been selected from one of the options fields. The button should appear as soon as the option has changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("option").change(function() {
    $("button").append(" <button>Click Submit</button>");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Love+Ya+Like+A+Sister" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="circle1">
  <select id="field1" name="age" class="dropdown1">
    <option> Select One </option>
    <option value="18-25">5-7</option>
    <option value="26-32">7-9</option>
    <option value="33-40">10-12</option>
    <option value="40+">12-15</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="submit_button">...</div>
```

Comment: `$("option")` -> `$("#field1")`

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with CSS from main.css - also `$("button")` is not the same as `$("#submit_button")` - please make sure you use the correct IDs

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the button already exist but set its display to none?

```
style = "display: none;"
```

and then when the option is selected, simply make it visible...

```
  $("button").show()
```

Comment: Not a shortcut. Your code was truly invalid mixing DOM and jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is just a library for achieving the same thing, why is it invalid to mix them?

Comment: Be consistent - and in your case write valid code. Your mix would never work since you tried a DOM access on a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the button for example

```
#submit_button { display:none;}
```

and then when something is checked just show it

```
  $('#field1').on('change', function() {
 $('#submit_button').show();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add a button on select change event like:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var r= $('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
        $("#button").append(r);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="button"> </div>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

However you can also hide the button then show it on select change event like:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#btn').show();
})
```

```css
#btn{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="new button"/>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will not allow the button to show when loading and also not allow it to hide when selecting nothing. Your select is missing a "please select"

Comment: I just tried to give the approach as per the OP's question. anyway thanks @mplungjan

Comment: But why not use OPs code? Your code now does not work

Answer (score 0):

Since all other answers are lacking something I will suggest this:

1. Use the correct ID
2. To toggle an existing button makes more sense
3. Note I gave the first option a `value=""` as it should have

```js
$(function() {
  $("#field1").on("change",function() {
    $("#submit_button").toggle(this.value!="");
  }).change(); // trigger when loading too
});
```

```css
#submit_button { display:none }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Love+Ya+Like+A+Sister" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
<div id="circle1">
  <select id="field1" name="age" class="dropdown1">
    <option value=""> Select One </option>
    <option value="18-25">5-7</option>
    <option value="26-32">7-9</option>
    <option value="33-40">10-12</option>
    <option value="40+">12-15</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="submit_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```